# $G$-set terminology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, group-actions

When a group action $G \times X \rightarrow X$ is defined with a group $G$ and a set $X$, why is there not a special name for the set $X$? I know that this is referred to as a $G$-set, but the set $X$ itself does not seem to have a special name without the "$G$" specification.

To illustrate the point: when we have the appropriate action of a ring $R$ on a set $M$ such that $R \times M \rightarrow M$, then the set $M$ is a "module" without specification of the "$R$", and then we can refer to the $R$-module if we want to be more specific. But we cannot refer to the "set" in the same way, it has to be "$G$-set". So I am wondering is there such a name that was used in this case?

Comment: You could refer to these generically as "sets with a group action", but there's nothing you can say about the general case anyway. (Whereas by comparison, every module is an abelian group.)

Comment: Not really, I don't think. Mathworld calls $X$ a "[group set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupSet.html)" but I have not seen that elsewhere and it doesn't cite any references. Perhaps the closest convention is calling $X$ a "space" after it has already defined to be a $G$-set.

Comment: But we should only call $M$ simply a module when the ring $R$ is understood. And being a module at least implies some structure apart from the action of $R$. Being a $G$-set does not provide any structure apart from the action of $G$, so there is nothing special about a set on which some unspecified group acts.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your point is. Groups act on *so many* things. For example, they act on other groups, and there is the theory of groups acting on trees, on graphs, on $\operatorname{CAT}(0)$ spaces... You name it, a group acts on it. On the other hand, a module is necessarily an abelian group.

Comment: @anon Interesting! I've never seen that but it would seem to be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of monoidal categories offers a unification of various notions spread out over mathematics. $G$-sets and $R$-modules are really the same notions. In every monoidal category, there is the notion of a monoid object, namely an object $G$ equipped with morphisms $1 \to G$ and $G \otimes G \to G$, satisfying unitality and associativity. Besides, there is the notion of a module object over that monoid object, namely an object $X$ equipped with a morphism $G \otimes X \to X$ satisfying unitality and associativity in a certain sense. For the cartesian monoidal category of sets, the monoid objects are precisely the monoids $G$ in the usual sense, and $G$-modules are usually called $G$-sets. But really, you could just stick to the general formalism and call them $G$-modules$^{(1)}$. For the monoidal category of abelian groups with the usual tensor product, the monoid objects are the rings in the usual sense, and $R$-modules in the general sense above are precisely the $R$-modules in the usual sense.

Back to the general case: For a $G$-module $(X,G \otimes X \xrightarrow{a} X)$ I would call $X$ the underlying object. It is not good to call it a module, because the action $a$ has been forgotten.

$^{(1)}$ You might object that this contradicts with the common meaning of $G$-modules as $R[G]$-modules, where $R$ is a ring which is understood. But in my opinion this only shows that this usual usage is not good. Why does one say $G$, the monoid (or often group) object in the category of *sets*, where one actually means the induced monoid object $R[G]$ in the category of *$R$-algebras*? It is [important and also quite useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389328) to distinguish objects of different categories. When $G$ is a monoid, it is understood to be a monoid object in the category of *sets*, and nothing else, so that every construction, in particular the definition of a module, refers to the category of sets. Therefore "$G$-modules" is *not* ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. So from this am I right to say that with the usual $R$-module, you would call $M$ the underlying object, which is the Abelian group in this case? I notice in most introductory texts (with no category theory) that they do refer to the underlying object as module, just as we call a group by its underlying set $G$, do you then think this is a bad convention?

Comment: Yes it is bad to ignore forgetful functors. For an $R$-module $(M, R \otimes M \to M)$ I would call $M$ the *underlying abelian group*. It is also quite common to denote it as the underlying additive group. The underlying set of a group should, of course, not be confused with the group itsself.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a semigroup then one use names "polygon" [Kilp M., Knauer U., Mikhalev A.V., Monoids, acts and categories] or "operand" [A. H. Clifford, G. B. Preston, The algebraic theory of semigroups] for $G$-sets (i.e. for the sets on which $G$ acts). So you can use them also, if you would like.

Comment: Though if you do, you should be sure to mention this is what you mean, because most people will probably not have seen those terms before.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft: OK, I added the answer.