# Is this "set quotient" known?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology

Let $A,B$ be subsets of a set $X$. Then there is a largest subset $C \subseteq X$ such that $C \cap A \subseteq B$. Explicitly, we have $C = \{x \in X : x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B\} = (X \setminus A) \cup B$. Does $C$ have a name? I would call $C$ the *set quotient* and denote it by $(B:A)$. Namely, there is an analogy$^1$ to [ideal quotients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient): If $A,B$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$, then there is a largest ideal $C$ such that $C \cdot A \subseteq B$, namely $C=(B:A) = \{x \in R : x \cdot A \subseteq B\}$.

$^1$ Actually it is more than just analogy. Both quotients are internal homs in monoidal preorders, the one being $(\wp(X),\subseteq,\cap)$ and the other one $(\mathrm{Id}(R),\subseteq,*)$.

Comment: It has many names: Heyting implication, relative pseudocomplement...

Comment: $(B:A)$ isn't good notation, because it omits the dependence on $X$. The notation $X\!\setminus\!\! A\cup B$ has the advantage that everyone can understand it immediately (add parentheses if you will).

Comment: @John: Since I regard $A,B$ as objects of the partial order of subsets of $X$, this $X$ *implicitly* belongs to the datum. If $X \subseteq X'$, then (for a category theorist) $A$ isn't really a subset of $X'$, but rather there is a *functor* $\wp(X) \to \wp(X')$ and $A$ shouldn't be confused with its image (of course set theory is full of such confusions).

Comment: @John: Besides, if $A,B$ are ideals of a ring $R$, then $(B:A)$ is a univerally accepted notation for the ideal quotient. Note that also here $R$ belongs implicitly to the datum. If $R \subseteq R'$ is a ring extension with $R'A \subseteq A$ (likewise $B$), then of course $A,B$ can be "seen" as ideals of $R'$ and in the partial order of ideals of $R'$ we can form $(B:A)$.

Comment: @John: This confusing abuse of notation can be avoided if we really stick to the general rule (which I try to promote here on math.SE (see for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389328) and other places) that different categories should be seen as disjoint, and that forgetful functors shouldn't be seen as identities. This clarifies and organizes a lot of mathematics! Objects of mathematics shouldn't "swim" between different categories, but rather each object lies in a *distinguished* category (and will *never* leave it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be a lattice that is cartesian closed as a category. Then $L$ is a [Heyting algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra), and the operation you describe is sometimes called the Heyting implication or relative pseudocomplement. If $L$ is moreover a boolean algebra then the Heyting implication $a \to b$ is given by the classical formula $(\lnot a) \vee b$, as you described.

Comment: An excellent book covering these issues completely in the first two chapters is "Stone Spaces" by Johnstone.